# Search Input with inline filters javascript like discord

Tags: javascript, string, search, filter

I am really stuck on this one, i'm trying to implement a search input that inlines some filters "guessed" by the user input. Is there any library able to do so? Any suggestion how to get this result?

The only good sample I could find is on Discord "Search bar".
[Short video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/O9MFOSmA_OA)

Im trying to do this in javascript, html, css.

Comment: Did you find one? I'm searching for this too.